# Access Compass Calibration from android app programatically

Tags: android, compass, calibration

I'm writing an app to measure magnetic field, and I'd like the first thing that user sees after launching the app is a request for accessing compass calibration feature like google map with infinity or eight pattern.

**Is there a way to launch calibration programmatically in android?**

For example

In iOS there is a privacy setting to allow your compass to use location services to help calibrate your devices compass. By default, this setting is disabled. Enabling this feature is highly recommended for good compass accuracy.

Open the “Settings” app
Tap “Privacy”
Tap “Location Services”
Tap “System Services”
Enable “Compass Calibration”

Comment: I want this too - I'm guessing from the lack of answers there is not one.  Best way I can think of for now is open an AlertDialog containing instruction for how to calibrate with google maps (1 - tap the blue dot, 2 - calibrate. 3 - Point camera around as instructed 4- if it fails, you will be given an option to calibrate compass with the figure 8).